# How to get the values out of Alternatitves?

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

Saying we have something like:

```
SomeFunction[
 ...
   {
      Alternatives[1, 2, 3] :> "something"
   }
 ...
]
```

How can I know if `SomeFunction` is called with `1` or `2` or `3`.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
A[t_] := Switch[t,
  1, 1,
  2 , 2
  ]


In[1]:= A[1]

Out[1]= 1
```

How can I write something like:

```
B[t_] := Switch[t,
  1 | 2, "Here should be the correct number"
  ]
```

Comment: Do you know how to [define functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) in Mathematica? If yes, please post proper Mathematica code.

Comment: I am not sure I if I can define this function. If could, I would not ask this question.
I want to have a function with Alternatives and :> and learn which element of Alternatives was actually called.

Comment: Consider the output of `{2, -1} /. c : (1 | 2 | 3) :> {c, "OK!"}`.

Comment: The problem is that it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve from your posted syntax

Comment: I'm guessing now: `SomeFunction[{x : Alternatives[1, 2, 3]}] := x`

Comment: Have you seen `Pattern` ref page?